# CircleCi is timed out after 10 minutes

Tags: javascript, circleci

I have a configuration that usually fails due to timeout of `npm install`.
I have 2 questions:

Why `no_output_timeout` did not take any effect? maybe there is a way to configure a max timeout for a specific step?

My config file:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run test
    no_output_timeout: 20m
  deploy:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run: npm install
      - run: npm run build
      - run: bash ./deploy.sh
    no_output_timeout: 20m
workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters: 
            branches:
              only: master
```

Bonus question: Is there a way to just make it faster with a better cpu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `timeout` modifier (default is 600s)?

Example with **1 hour** (3600 seconds):

```
dependencies:
  override:
    - bundle install: # note the colon here
        timeout: 3600 # note the double indentation (four spaces) here
```

[**More on Configuration Modifiers**](http://circleci.com/docs/1.0/configuration/#modifiers)

Answer (score 2):

*disclaimer: I'm a CircleCI Developer Advocate*

The answer marked correct isn't. That solution is for CircleCI 1.0, which isn't what your config is, and will be EOL'd in less than 60 days.

Based on the config you provided, you could do:

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:7.10
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          command: npm install
          no_output_timeout: 20m
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run test
  deploy:
    machine: true
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          command: npm install
          no_output_timeout: 20m
      - run: npm run build
      - run: bash ./deploy.sh

workflows:
  version: 2
  build-and-deploy:
    jobs:
      - build
      - deploy:
          requires:
            - build
          filters: 
            branches:
              only: master
```

The docs for `no_output_timeout` is [here](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/configuration-reference/#run).

Answer (score 1):

Circle today is having problems with NPM.

[Circle status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uggFk.jpg)

You can follow the status through this link:
https://status.circleci.com/